# Error when trying to run imported Play project

Tags: playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3

i'm trying to run a project made by a partner, but when I run the command `activator run` I receive this output:

```
[info] Loading project definition from  /home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/projectproxy-proxy/project
/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/projectproxy-  proxy/build.sbt:1: error: not found: value sname
sname := "project-proxy"
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

This was after several times of reinstalling play framework, previous times I received outputs like this one:

```
/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/project-proxy/build.sbt:12: error: not found: value javaJdbc
javaJdbc,
^
/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/project-proxy/build.sbt:13: error: not found: value javaEbean
javaEbean,
^
/home/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Project/project-proxy/build.sbt:14: error: not found: value cache
cache,
^
[error] Type error in expression
```

Thanks for your attention

**Edit:** Here's my build.sbt file:

```
sname := "project-proxy"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

resolvers ++= Seq(
  "Typesafe Repository" at   "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Sedis repository" at "http://pk11- scratch.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/",
  "jBCrypt Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  javaEbean,
  cache,
  "com.google.inject" % "guice" % "3.0",
  "log4j" % "log4j" % "1.2.17",
  "org.jboss.resteasy" % "resteasy-jaxrs" % "2.3.7.Final",
  "com.wordnik" % "swagger-core_2.10.0" % "1.2.5",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
  "ws.securesocial" %% "securesocial" % "2.1.4",
  "com.typesafe" %% "play-plugins-redis" % "2.1.1",
  "net.sf.opencsv" % "opencsv" % "2.1"
)

play.Project.playJavaSettings
fork in run := true
```

Here's my project/plugins.sbt:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at     "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.2")
```

Here's my project/build.properties file:

```
 sbt.version=0.13.0
```

One thing I forgot to mention is that I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 and my partners are running Windows 8.1. They are deploying the same project and having no issues.

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: shouldn't `sname` be `name`? It causes the rest of the errors of not finding the plugins

Comment: And I think for the `javaJdbc` etc, you might need to add `import play.PlayJava` at the top of your build.sbt file

Comment: @nbz I added the import line at the top of the build.sbt but it isn't working. It complains about javaJdbc, java EBean and cache

Comment: Do you use same activator/sbt version as your partner?

Comment: What about sname being changed to name?

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the problem is as follow:

You should add the play plugin to sbt by adding the following lines to your top level project/plugins.sbt:

```
// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.2.1")
```